# Save translation file of third party plugin in a custom plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, translation, localization

I have a custom plugin that I install on a handful of client sites. All the client sites uses a third party premium plugin, and I have translated that plugin to another language and saved the translation fil in the /wp-content/languages/loco/plugins folder. So every time I edit the translation file in my local installation I have to manually copy and overwrite the translation file on each client site. It works but it takes time and the risk of failure and forgetfulness is present!

It would be awesome if it was possible to manage the translation file in a more automatic/controlled way eg. saving the files in my custom plugin or in a github repository.

I could of course ask the developer of the premium plugin to incorporate my translations but I've tweaked the plugin to my liking, however it doesn't conform to how it was intended. Therefore, it does not make sense to share my translation with the public.

Is it possible to save the files in my custom plugin?

Thanks

Comment: Just throwing an idea out: is it possible to host the translation file externally (e.g. on a site that you own), and then link to that file on every client site you create? For example, put in the .../loco/plugins folder, put a .php file that just contains `include "https://externalsite.com/directory/translation.php";`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I don't think it will work. I would prefer to have some code in my custom plugin that tells WordPress that it should load the custom translation file from either a subfolder in the custom plugin or from a private git repo.

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-contents) help? Using GitHub's REST API it looks like you can request repo contents with JS, and then use [PHP's `base64_decode()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128433/how-to-fetch-content-of-single-file-from-private-git-repo-with-php) to get the contents of the file. I don't know that it's an intended way of using GitHub but it's a start.